# How can I write a regex that splits a string but ignores an escape sequence of the separator?

Tags: php, regex, split, escaping

I'm looking to use PHP's [`mb_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) to split a string that is colon-separated, but ignores an escaped colon (i.e. `\:`).

For instance:

`Part A is here:Part B\: is over here:Part C\ is here:Part \\:D is here`

needs to be split into:

1. `Part A is here`
2. `Part B: is over here`
3. `Part C\ is here`
4. `Part \:D is here`

I'm not really sure how to go about this. Any advice?

Comment: Using str_getcsv() might be a better alternative

Comment: @MarkBaker: Is `str_getcsv()` UTF-8-safe, though? I'm hesitant with PHP's string functions, because they're hardly ever multibyte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try splitting on:

```
(?<!\\):
```

`(?<!\\)` is a negative lookbehind and will make `:` not match if it is preceeded by `\`.

[Note I never tried `mb_split`, but this should work with `preg_split`]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/function.preg-grep.php has (also) that kind of logic provided by an "inverted" switch, which will return the opposites of the matches.

Comment: Should I just run a kind of string replace function on the result set to replace instances of `\:` with `:`, then? For instance, your answer splits it perfectly into four pieces, but Part B still reads: `Part B\: is over here`.

Comment: @MMiller Oh oops, I didn't notice that there were also changes in the split parts. I'm afraid I don't know PHP enough to help more than that :( Running a replace of `\:` would be affecting the last element of the array as well, right? I guess I'll remove my answer later.

Comment: Don't remove your answer, I figured it out. I'll just add my answer as well. Couldn't have done this without your help.

Comment: @MMiller Okay. That said, I just [tried it out](http://ideone.com/svVdXi), and for some reason, I had to double escape the backslash on there... I find it a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

This is my complete solution for searchers' reference.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('mb_str_replace')) {
    function mb_str_replace ($needle, $replacement, $haystack) {
        // Courtesy of marc at ermshaus dot org: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#86120
        $needleLength = mb_strlen($needle);
        $replacementLength = mb_strlen($replacement);
        $pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle);
        while ($pos !== false) {
            $haystack = mb_substr($haystack, 0, $pos).$replacement.mb_substr($haystack, $pos+$needleLength);
            $pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos+$replacementLength);
        }
        return $haystack;
    }
}

$str = <<<EOD
Part A is here:Part B\: is over here:Part C\ is here:Part \\\:D is here
EOD;
    /* Why did I have to use "\\\:D" in a heredoc? No idea.
       I thought "\\:D" would be sufficient, but for some
       reason the backslash was parsed anyways. Which kinda
       makes heredocs useless to me. */

echo "$str<br>", PHP_EOL;

$arr = mb_split('(?<!\\\):', $str);
    // Courtesy of Jerry: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1578604/jerry
foreach ($arr as &$val) {
    $val = mb_str_replace('\:', ':', $val);
}
unset($val);

echo '<pre>', print_r($arr, true), '</pre>';
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Part A is here:Part B\: is over here:Part C\ is here:Part \\:D is here
Array
(
    [0] => Part A is here
    [1] => Part B: is over here
    [2] => Part C\ is here
    [3] => Part \:D is here
)
```